# How to fireselectionChanged Event in igCombo only with mouse click?

Tags: infragistics, autosuggest, selectionchanged, ignite-ui, igcombo

I am using infragistics combo box. The data is loaded into the combobox after rendering. I have turned on the auto-suggest feature. The problem is that when i start typing in the combobox, selectionChanged event is fired as the first item in the dropdown list is selected automatically. I only want the selectionChanged to be fired when a user selects options from the dropdown using mouse click or by pressing the enter. Following is the my render code for igCombo.

```
searchTextCombo && searchTextCombo.igCombo({    
        valueKey: "Value",    
        textKey: "Key",    
        multiSelection: "off",    
        enableClearButton: true,    
        closeDropDownOnSelect: true,    
        virtualization: true,   
        dataSource: configuration.testUrl,    
        showDropDownButton: false,    
        filteringType: "local",    
        filteringCondition: "contains",    
        highlightMatchesMode: "contains",    
        selectionChanged: function (evt, ui) {
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the `selectionChanged` event to fire on typing, then you need to set `autoSelectFirstMatch` to `false`. By default it's true.

```
searchTextCombo.igCombo({    
    valueKey: "Value",    
    textKey: "Key",    
    multiSelection: "off",    
    enableClearButton: true,    
    closeDropDownOnSelect: true,
    virtualization: true,   
    dataSource: configuration.testUrl,    
    showDropDownButton: false,    
    filteringType: "local",    
    filteringCondition: "contains",    
    highlightMatchesMode: "contains",
    autoSelectFirstMatch: false,
    selectionChanged: function (evt, ui) {
    }
});
```

[Here's the API doc.](http://www.igniteui.com/help/api/2016.1/ui.igcombo#options:autoSelectFirstMatch)